# Regular expression for returning lines of dialogue

Tags: python, python-3.x

-I am a beginner python coder so bear with me!

- A line of complete dialog is defined as text that **starts on its own line and starts and ends with double quotation marks (i.e. ")**.

what i have so far is,

```
def q_4():
  pattern = r'^\"\w*\"'
  return re.compile(pattern, re.M|re.IGNORECASE)
```

but for some reason it only returns one instance with one word between the two double quotes. How can i go about grasping full lines?

Answer (score 1):

Try searching on the pattern `\"[^"]+\"`:

```
inp = """Here is a quote: "the quick brown fox jumps over
the lazy dog" and here is another "blah
blah blah" the end"""

dialogs = re.findall(r'\"([^"]+)\"', inp)
print(dialogs)
```

This prints:

```
['the quick brown fox jumps over\nthe lazy dog', 'blah\nblah blah']
```